# adding multiple p5.js canvases into html

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm currently building a website that has multiple p5.js canvases with my own images, using instance mode so I can get multiple canvases up on the html page. However, I don't think I'm getting the syntax correct.

```js
// first sketch
var sketch1 = function (p) {
  const NUM_IMGS = 4;
  imgs = [];
  let currentImg = 0;
  p.preload = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_IMGS; i++) {
      imgs[1] = p.loadImage("images/mag.png");
      imgs[2] = p.loadImage("images/outfits.png");
      imgs[3] = p.loadImage("images/photographer1.png");
      imgs[4] = p.loadImage("images/photographer2.png");
    }
  };

  p.setup = function () {
    const sketch1 = p.createCanvas(450, 300);
  };
  setupButtons();
};

p.draw = function () {
  p.image(imgs[currentImg], 0, 0);
};

const setupButtons = (_) => {
  previous = p.createButton("⏪");
  previous.position(p.width * 0.6 - 100, p.height);

  previous.mouseClicked((_) => {
    if (p.currentImg > 0) p.currentImg--;
  });

  next = p.createButton("⏩");
  next.position(p.width * 0.3 + 100, p.height);

  next.mouseClicked((_) => {
    if (p.currentImg < p.imgs.length - 1) p.currentImg++;
  });
};

// second sketch
var sketch2 = function (p) {
  let y;
  let z;
  let a;

  let switcher;

  let currentImage;

  p.preload = function () {
    y = p.loadImage("girls.png");
    z = p.loadImage("bow.png");
    a = p.loadImage("rose.png");
    b = p.loadImage("reds.png");
  };

  p.setup = function () {
    p.createCanvas(250, 300);

    switcher = createButton("see my pics");
    switcher.position(900, 1200);

    switcher.mousePressed(changeImg);
  };

  p.draw = function () {};

  p.changeImg = function () {
    if (currentImage == y) currentImage = z;
    else if (currentImage == z) currentImage = a;
    else if (currentImage == a) currentImage = b;
    else {
      currentImage = y;
    }

    image(currentImage, 0, 0, 250, 300);
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I'm getting the error message "p is not defined". I can't seem to get p5 to activate "instance mode" [using this code as a reference](https://editor.p5js.org/slow_izzm/sketches/535SiO_aC), [and using this code as a reference](https://editor.p5js.org/jarivkin/sketches/9-BMW9iiX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice: slow down! This code looks like it was written in one fell swoop, blindly hoping/assuming that it'll work. When it didn't, there was no obvious entry point for debugging because the complexity had grown far beyond your understanding.

A much better strategy is to code slowly, running the code as soon as you make any change to verify that it still works. If it doesn't work, you'll know exactly what to do to fix it because you've only made one small change.

Start with simple, minimal examples, like the [p5 instance mode example from the docs](https://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html), then build up only once you've thoroughly tested the code to convince yourself it works. Both of the linked sketches are non-instance mode slideshows. Instead of trying to get instance mode, plus 2 sketches, plus slideshow logic all working at once, focus on one goal at a time. Start with getting a single instance working that shows a single image. Then make it a slideshow. Then add a second sketch. If those steps are too large, discretize the problem into [even smaller steps](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) that are achievable and verifiable.

You can think of programming as exploring a dark room full of pits. If you rush in willy-nilly, you'll fall into a pit. If you go slowly, testing the next step ahead of you, you'll make it to the goal safely.

---

Here's a list of some of the errors I noticed:

- `p.draw` and `setupButtons` were in the global scope, leading to your main error. These need to be inside of the p5 instance closure where they have access to the `p` parameter. You'd have probably seen this if you used an [autoformatter](https://prettier.io/playground) (I already ran one on the question code for you).
- Your code is missing calls to `new p5(sketch1)` to initialize the instance.
- Confusion about when to use `p.` in front of a variable. If you own the variable and it was declared in your sketch closure with `let`, don't add `p.` in front. `p.` is only used to refer to a piece of data in the p5 library. Examples:

  - `p.changeImg` should be `const changeImg`
  - `p.imgs` should be `imgs`
  - `p.currentImg` should be `currentImg`
  - `createButton("see my pics");` should be `p.createButton("see my pics");`
- `for (let i = 0; i < NUM_IMGS; i++) {` does nothing except load the same images into indices 1, 2, 3, 4 over and over.
- Arrays are 0-indexed, but `imgs[0]` was never set.
- `setupButtons();` should be called from p5's `setup` function so the instance is properly initialized.
- There are global variables all over the place. These can cause very subtle bugs--essentially, data from one closure leaks into the other closure, wreaking havoc. Always scope variables tightly with `let` and `const`. Examples include `next`, `previous` and `imgs`. A [linter](https://eslint.org/play/) will show you these mistakes. Adding `"use strict";` to the top of your script can be helpful too.
- `changeImg` uses separate variables when an array would be easier to manage.
- `currentImage` was never initialized in sketch 2.

Here's code that is far from perfect, but fixes most of the above problems. I've moved a few positions around and added dummy images to make the example runnable. I'm hoping you can tweak it from here back to what you intended.

```js
// first sketch
var sketch1 = function (p) {
  const imgs = [];
  let currentImg = 0;

  p.preload = function () {
    imgs[0] = p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/450/300");
    imgs[1] = p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/450/301");
    imgs[2] = p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/450/302");
    imgs[3] = p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/450/303");
  };

  p.setup = function () {
    const sketch1 = p.createCanvas(450, 300);
    setupButtons();
  };

  const setupButtons = () => {
    const previous = p.createButton("⏪");
    previous.position(10, 10);

    previous.mouseClicked(() => {
      if (currentImg > 0) currentImg--;
    });

    const next = p.createButton("⏩");
    next.position(40, 10);
    next.mouseClicked(() => {
      if (currentImg < imgs.length - 1) currentImg++;
    });
  };

  p.draw = function () {
    p.image(imgs[currentImg], 0, 0);
  };
};

// second sketch
var sketch2 = function (p) {
  let images;
  let switcher;
  let currentImage = 0;

  p.preload = function () {
    images = [
      p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/250/300"),
      p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/250/301"),
      p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/250/302"),
      p.loadImage("https://picsum.photos/250/303"),
    ]
  };

  p.setup = function () {
    p.createCanvas(250, 300);

    switcher = p.createButton("see my pics");
    switcher.position(90, 120);
    switcher.mousePressed(changeImg);

    p.noLoop();
  };

  const changeImg = function () {
    p.image(images[currentImage], 0, 0, 250, 300);
    currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % images.length;
  };
};

new p5(sketch1);
new p5(sketch2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```